# How to access private class's property from public static method in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have a class (yii2 widget) that has private properties and public static functions. When I try to access a private property from the static method like `$this->MyPrivateVar` an error is generated regarding that I don't have to use `$this` in non object context! The following is a snippet of my code:

```
class JuiThemeSelectWidget extends Widget
{
  private $list;
  private $script;
  private $juiThemeSelectId = 'AASDD5';
  public $label;
  ....
 public static function createSelectList($items)
  {
    $t = $this->juiThemeSelectId;
    ...
  }
```

I tried the following, but it seems that undergoes to infinite loop `Maximum execution time of 50 seconds exceeded`!

```
public static function createSelectList($items)
  {
    $t = new JuiThemeSelectWidget;
    $juiThemeSelectId = $t->juiThemeSelectId;
    ...
  }
```

So how could I access the private `juiThemeSelectId` from the static method?

Comment: Is `$items` a `Widget` class?

Comment: No, it is just a parameter passed to the method from another method. @CommuSoft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sort answer is: You can't access a non-static property in a static method. You don't have access to `$this` in a static method.

What you could do is just to change the property to static like:

```
private static $juiThemeSelectId = 'AASDD5';
```

And then access it with this:

```
echo self::$juiThemeSelectId;
```

For more information about the keyword `static` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

And a quote from there:

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.

Comment: As you said, I set the property to be `private static` and then I tried to access it from the public static method as `$t = self::$juiThemeSelectId;` but it gives the error: `Getting unknown property: common\libs\JuiThemeSelectWidget::juiThemeSelectId`

Comment: @sємsєм Can you please how the code which you use now to get this error.

Comment: Sorry, your solution works fine, I just forgot that I called it in another line as `$this`.

Comment: @sємsєм No problem, glade that i could help you!

Answer (score 0):

you can access it using `self`:

```
public static function createSelectList($items)
{
  $t = self::juiThemeSelectId;
  ...
}
```

Comment: When using `self` as you reared the following error is generated: `Undefined class constant 'juiThemeSelectId'`

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't realized, that `juiThemeSelectId` isn't `static` in your example... see @Rizier123 answere